# Stuck in system recovery

Tags: boot

I have a hTC *D626w*, after an interrupted update, it does not boot any more. When I enter recovery mode, I see the following message at the bottom of the page:

```
No file end with factory_update.zip found in SD card.
```

The message persists after removing the SD card.

I chose **wipe cache partition** and **wipe data/factory reset**. But after selecting **reboot system now**, a white page appears on which I see hTC.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my device?

Answer (score 1):

Interrupting an Android update is not a good idea as your device is now in an "in between" state that is not usable.

Most likely you have to flash a complete factory image (also called RUU image) of your device to recover it.

Usually HTC devices support fastboot, which should allow to flash such an image to your device. Check the [HTC ROM Download page](https://www.htc.com/us/support/rom-downloads.html) for an image matching your specific device.

Answer (score 0):

### A system update could have been making important system configuration changes when it got interrupted.

You should have an incomplete ( Corrupted ) system, this is why you should never interrupt a System firmware update.

### What to do now ?

- First you need to unlock your bootloader at the HTC Dev website
  [htcdev.com/bootloader](https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader)
- After that, you can try to repair your device via Fastboot by
  flashing the stock images back.

Considering the information I found suggest that you still have the update.zip and you might have a MTK CPU.

- You can alternatively try to flash the Firmware using SP Flash Tool
  v5.17 or above.

You will need to extract your Update.zip file and find any .IMG files... E.g, boot.img, recovery.img and especially system.img

If you can find boot.img, try to flash that with Fastboot first... Then try the rest...

If you have an update that contains folders, you will have difficulty installing it without a custom recovery.

With SP Flash Tool, you DO NOT need to unlock your bootloader, as you can flash the bootloader also.

I can find only a few ROM - Firmware online, however the firmware I found doesn't have Gapps included ( Google Apps ) ...

Do you have an MTK CPU ?